# Akka ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic not routing to the same dispatcher thread consistently

Tags: java, akka, consistent-hashing

I am trying to use Akka's `ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic` to guarantee that messages with the same key are routed to the same Actor. It is important that messages with the same key are processed in FIFO ordering. Messages with different keys can be routed to different Actors and processed in parallel freely. I am not using Akka in distributed mode.

The messages are actually JSON messages being read from a RabbitMQ broker so my Master actor receives an AMQP message and uses the routing key as the message key. The same key is also in the message itself. The actor is part of a Spring application.

My Master Actor looks like this:

```
@Named("MessageHandlerMaster")
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MessageHandlerMaster extends UntypedActor {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageHandlerMaster.class);

  private Router router;

  @Autowired
  public MessageHandlerMaster(final SpringProps springProps) {

  List<Routee> routees = Stream.generate(() -> {
      ActorRef worker = getContext().actorOf(springProps.create(MessageHandlerWorker.class));
      getContext().watch(worker);
      return new ActorRefRoutee(worker);
    }).limit(5) //todo: configurable number of workers
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    router = new Router(new ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic(getContext().system()), routees);
  }

  public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof Message) {
      Message amqpMessage = (Message) message;
      String encoding = getMessageEncoding(amqpMessage);
      try {
        String json = new String(amqpMessage.getBody(), encoding);
        String routingKey = amqpMessage.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey();
        log.debug("Routing message based on routing key " + routingKey);
        router.route(new ConsistentHashingRouter.ConsistentHashableEnvelope(json, routingKey), getSender());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log.warn("Unknown content encoding sent in message! {}", encoding);
      }
    } else if (message instanceof Terminated) {
      //if one of the routee's died, remove it and replace it
      log.debug("Actor routee terminated!");
      router.removeRoutee(((Terminated) message).actor());
      ActorRef r = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(MessageHandlerWorker.class));
      getContext().watch(r);
      router = router.addRoutee(new ActorRefRoutee(r));
    }
  }

  private static String getMessageEncoding(Message message) {
    String encoding = message.getMessageProperties().getContentEncoding();
    if ((encoding == null) || (encoding.equals(""))) {
      encoding = "UTF-8";
    }
    return encoding;
  }
}
```

I am initially getting the master once by:

```
this.master = actorSystem.actorOf(springProps.create(MessageHandlerMaster.class), "master");
```

and then just submitting the messages to it by:

```
master.tell(message, ActorRef.noSender());
```

But when I print the logs from my worker's `onReceive()` I see that different dispatcher threads are being used sometimes for the same key.

Also it is not clear why sometimes the same dispatcher thread is being used for the Master actor and for a Worker actor. Shouldn't this be asynchronous message passing between threads?

```
16:45:13.359 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.359 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.360 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerMaster - Routing message based on routing key 10420186
16:45:13.361 [aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG c.u.o.a.actors.MessageHandlerWorker - Handling message for 10420186
```

As you can see here, the dispatcher thread for the Worker processing message with key 10420186 was sometimes 9 and sometimes 10. The Master actor sometimes also used these 2 threads.

How can I be sure that the `ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic` is actually working and the same thread processes messages with the same key? Am I doing something wrong in my router initialisation?

Comment: I think actors are not bound to threads. So there is nothing wrong in the attached log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @vrudkovsk is right with his comment. I think you are getting confused between threads and actors. Actors are just objects in memory that have an address and a mailbox. Dispatchers are essentially thread pools that perform actions with the actor. Example actions are:

- dequeue a message from a mailbox to process it in an actor
- enqueue a message to a mailbox.

Different threads can perform actions for the same actor. That's decided by the dispatcher. Akka ensures that only one thread at a time will be processing a message within an actor. That does not mean it will always be the same thread.

If you want to ensure they are coming to the same actor, I would recommend logging the actor path or address by using `context.self.path` or  `context.self.path.address` since those are unique identifiers within the same `ActorSystem`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in this case, do I still have the assurance that if I have 5 Worker actors, irrespective of which Thread is being used for Actor 1, since I am using `ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic`, there is no way that a second dispatcher thread will pick up another message that should be routed to Actor 1 before the previous message is processed?

Comment: That's correct. The `ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic` ensures that your message will end up in the right actor irrespective of which thread does the work.